# oracle data pump export dump file to UAT environment

Tags: oracle, export, datapump, impdp, expdp

I am trying to learn data pump export and import of tables in oracle. I am asked to export from the device to UAT/sit environment. I have a doubt. I have been practicing this on my laptop with 2 pluggable databases. As it's on the same device, the directory object has no problem. what if I had to export it to the UAT environment? how would I use the impdp to import?

i am still a beginner in oracle.

Comment: These functionalities have documentation and judging by your description you're doing this for work and I strongly suggest that you get familiar with them by yourself since nobody would take responsibility for your actions but yourself.

Comment: DIRECTORY objects only point to locations on the local server. If you export to a folder on your development host you will need to copy the export dump file to a folder with an applicable DIRECTORY on your UAT server and run impdp from there, *or* use a database link and perform the data pump directly over the network. If you are just beginning, I highly advise copying the file over the direct network connection: there's less to configure and go wrong, and progress is easier to monitor.

Comment: _"As it's on the same device, the directory object has no problem. what if I had to export it to the UAT environment?"_   Ummm   . . . create an appropriate directory object in the destination database .... ?